Issues while displaying company logo using multi tenancy with laravel and nuxt js
I have tenancy for laravel installed in my project due to this my images are being uploaded correctly and storing in storage folder in specific tenant folder and then image name !! but how can i display this? for storage if i use storage_path it takes whole path from
file:///C:/wamp64/www/toplimo/toplimo_server/storage/tenanta21e21ae-e338-4355-9c20-686335d9dea6/logos/ehZImdggil6PTsuUBVQAQGNkCthdFFBUCYI4o7GT.jpg !! so for storage i am just storing logos/name of image ! thats it but if i use storage_path while accessing then it gives this and says not allowed to load local resource !!
$path = $request->file('logo')->store('logo');
    
            // Save the file name to the database
            $company->logo = $path;
            $company->save();

This is how i am saving data but if i use this for fetching profile details along with logo  ---------
$profile_data->company_logo = storage_path($company_details->logo);

it gives above link file:///C:/wamp64/www/toplimo/toplimo_server/storage/tenanta21e21ae-e338-4355-9c20-686335d9dea6/logos/ehZImdggil6PTsuUBVQAQGNkCthdFFBUCYI4o7GT.jpg and i am unable to use

$profile_data->company_logo = Storage::disk('logos')->path($company_details->logo); 

help me to display it !! i want to display over here
if (this.profileData && this.profileData.company_logo) {
              // Assuming your backend serves the logos from a specific URL, like '/logos/'
              // You may need to adjust this URL based on your server setup
              this.form.company.logo =  'http://domain1.localhost:8000/logos/' + this.profileData.company_logo.split('/').pop();
              console.log(this.form.company.logo);
            } 

this.form.company.logo should display proper value and i am running server on domain1.localhost:8000
i dont want to publically make my images /logos available so it should pick from tenant only

To store it, i have used -
        $File = $request->file('logo');
        $path = $request->file('logo')->store('logos');

        // Save the file name to the database
        $company->logo = $path;
        $company->save();

        $stored = Storage::disk('public')->put("logos", $File);
        $url = tenant_asset($stored);
        return response()->json(['success' =>$url], 200);   

and it gives answer as  "success": "http://domain1.localhost:8000/tenancy/assets/logos/RoNnhVVmuQqgLM2czVncOjgb1EYizX7Q1sfoPrUB.png" so for displaying it,
       console.log(response.success);
      // Remove extra slashes from the response URL
      let cleanedUrl = response.success.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");

      // Set the cleaned URL to the form's company logo property
      this.form.company.logo = cleanedUrl;
      this.$toast.success("Company Logo Updated Successfully");
      console.log(this.form.company.logo);


This, this fixes your issue?

Yes !! Why would i add otherwise ?

Please accept it when you can then. And you'll be shocked by the amount of people that misuse an answer for an edit here.
